# Finding tangent for angle of right triangle

Tags: geometry

Given : Right $\triangle ABC$ $CH$ is altitude and $AH =2$, $BH=8$. Here is drawing[image]

Find the $tan \angle CBA$

Here is how I solved the exercise:
From that fact that $ABC$ is right triangle $=>$ $AC^2=AH*AB$ 
(Altitude on hypotenuse theorem) $=> AC = \sqrt{2*10} = \sqrt{20}$ and
$tan \angle CBA = \frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{2*\sqrt{5}}{10}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$

However the answer in test is $\frac{1}{2}$. I can't find my mistake.

Comment: CH =ah*ab.  Not ac

Comment: @fleablood no, that's right what he wrote. But he found sin, not tan

Comment: Oops, I misread ab as hb, ie ch^2 = ah*hb.  Which wasn't the intent.  I should learn not to post comments in rushed minutes between doctors appointments.

Comment: Right.  Angle cba = cbh so tan= opp/adj   = ca/cb (not ab) or ch/hb.  (For some reason, I'm finding triangle chb easier to work with than abc which is we I made the mistaken first post.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know : $$CH = \sqrt{AH \cdot BH}$$,
Now $$tan(CBA) = \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: My I ask why did you prefer to use $CH$ instant of $AC$?

Comment: @Planet_Earth it's easier , because of using your values you could evaluate $CH$. Then if you consider CHB triangle you may find your tangent

Comment: Yeah, it's clear for me how you did it. However both of the answers are provided(together with $\frac{2*\sqrt{5}}{5}$ and 2), I thought that there is some logic behind this(using $CH$ instant of $AC$)

Comment: @Planet_Earth actually I thought that it's easier

Comment: If you want to use AC you can.  But tan = CA/CB instead of the CA/AB you wrote.  (I believe the triangle being upside down temporarily threw you off; It threw me off briefly.)  AC = $\sqrt 20$ so CH = 4 (20- 4 = 16 = $CH^2$) so CB =$\sqrt 80$ ($8^2 + 4^2 = 80$) and AC/CB = 1/2.

Comment: CH, IMO being more "central" (the common side to two triangles and an altitude to a third) is more "flexible" and "direct".   But there are always multiple ways to do things.